# sql server select into variable and count result

Tags: sql-server, select, count, combinations

Something very simple, but I cannot get it working for me :)

```
select x.name, count(x.name) from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...
```

It throws an error, that the x.name isn't used with group by.

```
select x.name from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...
```

works fine and returns e.g. 6 names

```
select count(x.name) from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...
```

works also fine and returns e.g. the number 6

But the combination is not working, when I tried to add the group by:

```
select x.name, count(x.name) from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...
group by x.name
```

it worked, but all counts were 1 and not 6.

The thing is, I could firstly get the count into variable, then write the long sql statement just to get the names, but I don't want to write the long complex select statement twice. There has to be some way to do the combination in one select: get all names and by the way tell me how many they were.

Thanks

P.S.

```
name    bla1    bla2
a       ...     ...     
a       foo     ...     
b       foo     ...     
c       ...     ...     
d       foo     ...     
d       foo     ...     
b       foo     ...     
c       foo     ...
```

The result of x.name where bla1 = foo would be:

```
a
b
d
d
b
c
```

The result of count(x.name) where bla1 = foo would be:

```
6
```

My desired result of:

```
...variable definitions
select @foundName = x.name, @numOfAllFoundNames = count(x.name)
from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...
```

should be: 
@foundName = a (just one of the names, no matter which one)
@numOfAllFoundNames = 6

Comment: plz share some sample table content to explain the way it works. COUNT is an aggregate function and it expects either grouping or applied on complete table. What is the output you are expecting really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `@@rowcount` after the query;

```
select x.name from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...

select 'the number of rows is:', @@rowcount
```

As an aside, if you request a non-aggregate field (`name`) and an aggregated field (`count(name)`) you must provide a `group by` to tell the server *what* to count; you see 1's because `group by name` applies the `count` to every *distinct* name in the set - E.g. you would see 1 less row and `2` if a name was repeated.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
select x.name, count(x.name) over () cnt 
from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...
```

Comment: cool this is working too, but how is this working actually. What is this construct over () cnt???

Comment: I think it's like an additional select with group by, but a little bit more efficient and more comfortable. For more see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) after selecting the names to get the number of rows returned by your complicated query.  Otherwise, there's no simple way to get the number of names in the same query that selects each name.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.

```
...variable definitions
set @numOfAllFoundNames = 0;
select @foundName = x.name, @numOfAllFoundNames = @numOfAllFoundNames+1
from <table_name> x where ...<complex and long>...
```

Comment: -1 because "@foundName = x.name" only works for single-row select, and "@numOfAllFoundNames = @numOfAllFoundNames+1" is only meaningful for a multi-row select.

Comment: @forcey: cool this works too, thanks (@JohnC I don't understand what exactly you mean by that, but I've validated it and it worked for me, when names were 0,1,>1, so it works as expected)

Comment: @JohnC are you sure @foundName=x.name only works for single-row select?

Comment: @forcey, a variable can only have one value at a time.

Comment: @JohnC and the op wants just one (any one) value returned. The last value qualifies perfectly.

Comment: @forcey, I'm sorry I must have mis-read the question. I thought OP wanted all rows, with the count in each.

Comment: No, I re-read the question and still think OP wants all 6 rows.

Comment: @JohnC: I fully accept this answer too, it worked for me, I really just want one of the names and the number of all names (I don't care which name I will get first). If this is satisfied I am ok, except there is some hidden problem, which I don't see at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the little-used COMPUTE clause:

```
SELECT x.name
FROM [table]
WHERE [... ]
COMPUTE COUNT(x.name)
```

Just be wary that COMPUTE has been deprecated.

Comment: since there are other valid answers I won't use the depricated compute :), thanks anyway